# jQuery each nextAll prevAll

Tags: jquery, each

How do you loop through each element before, and each element after the clicked element?

This works

```
$(".bar").bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).each(function(i,o) {
        $(o).css('z-index',i);
    });
});
```

but this

```
$(".bar").bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).nextAll.each(function(i,o) {
        $(o).css('z-index',i);
    });
});
```

returns `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Your `nextAll` should prob be `nextAll()`

Comment: try this: `$(this).nextAll().each(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextAll is a function that needs to be executed, not a property that you are accessing.  Needs to be this:

```
$(this).nextAll().each(function(i,o){...});
```

Comment: Thanks.  And with that, i finally got my layout working.  http://codepen.io/dcdev/full/azvGwm/